# Time complexity in Algorithms. Choosing Big-O and omega

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

So I have this assignment, where we're supposed to look through the following algorithm:

```
 Input: An array A storing n elements
 Output: An array B, where B[i] = A[0] + A[1] + ... + A[i].

    for i = 0 to n-1
    Add the numbers A[0] thru A[i].
     Store the result in B[i].
```

After that we're supposed to state the time complexity of the algorithm by first stating it in the form O(f(n)). Afterwards we're supposed to show that the time complexity is also Ω(f(n)).

Now I've done the first part and said that because T(n) = n(n-1)/2 we can state that T(n) = O(n^2).

The problem I have is with the second part of the assignment. How can the algorithm also be Ω(n^2)? It doesn't make any sense from the definitions of those notations. If Ω(n^2) then that implies that T(n) = n(n-1)/2 grows faster that f(n) = n^2. And that can't be true.

I know that when we reach large numbers of n, T(n) is dominated by the square term n^2. But f(n) = n^2 is still not a lower bound to T(n) right? So how can it be Ω(n^2)?

I'm sorry if my English was bad, but I hope you understand my question and can help me. I'm really confused.

Answer (score 1):

> The problem I have is with the second part of the assignment. How can
>   the algorithm also be Ω(n^2) ?? It doesn't make any sense from the
>   definitions of those notations.. If Ω(n^2) then that implies that T(n)
>   = n(n-1)/2 grows faster that f(n) = n^2. And that can't be true..

Remember that the definitions for both Big-O and Big-Omega involve constants.

To show that it is in Ω(n<sup>2</sup>), you want a constant c such that n(n-1)/2 ≥ cn<sup>2</sup> for sufficiently large n (i.e. all n above a certain value). Your observation just shows that said constant can't be 1.

Comment: Thank you for replying! Hmm, ok I understand that but how could i prove what value c could be? If the constants value is anything above 1 the statement does not hold..?

Comment: Note that n(n-1)/2 = n^2/2 - n/2, and so n(n-1)/2 - cn = (1/2-c)n^2 - n/2. You want this to be a positive value (so that the inequality holds). I'll let you play around with it.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help!
I set n=2 and then got that c≤0.25. Is that a valid answer?

Comment: That looks right, but if you have a right answer, you should be able to convince yourself that it's true.